# Drools - nesting rules using a fact class

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules

This post suggests adding some fact classes as a way of nesting rules.
http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-can-I-nested-rules-td4020488.html#a4020681

What I would like to know - is there a guarantee that "Age and gender women" executes before "Pregnant" and "Pregnant" before "Pregnant2"? 
As far I have noticed that is always the case in my application. But, is it documented somewhere in drools documentation or is it just the house of cards that is waiting to collapse?

```
    rule "Age and gender women" 
    when 
        $p : Person(p1 >= 12 && p2 = 1) 
    then 
        insertLogical( new CouldHaveBeenPregnant($p) ); 
end 

rule "Pregnant" 
    when 
        $p : Person(p3 > 1) 
        CouldHaveBeenPregnant( person == $p ) 
    then 
        insertLogical( new HasBeenPregnant($p) ); 
end 

rule "Pregnant2" 
    no-loop 
    when 
        $p : Person(p4 <= P3) 
        HasBeenPregnant( person == $p ) 
    then 
        $p.setStatus("OK"); 
        update($p); 
end
```

Thanks for help in advance

**EDIT:**
My problem arises when I have to add a new rule, say "not Pregnant", where I have to do something when person is NOT HasBeenPregnant( person == $p ). The inference principle doesn't work sometimes (as expected). Because, sometimes, "not Pregnant" rule gets executed first and it turns out later that the person is pregnant i.e, "Pregnant" gets true later on. But the outcome for "not Pregnant" has already run.

So, any suggestion on how to overcome this?

Comment: As far as I know, the order in which the rules are tested should not matter. When a fact is inserted (or removed or changed) that is relevant to some other rules, those rules are tested again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee of the order in which rules are evaluated when they all match. However, in the example above, the order is being forced in the best way.

The first rule will activate when there is a Person fact in working memory with the appropriate properties.

The second rule will not activate until there is a Person in working memory **and** a fact called CouldHaveBeenPregnant, which references the person. CouldHaveBeenPregnant is only in working memory when rule 1 has activated and inserted it.

Likewise, the third rule will only activate when there is a Person with matching properties **and** a HasBeenPregnant fact referencing that person. The HasBeenPregnant fact is only inserted by the second rule.

i.e. Rule 3 cannot activate until after rule 2, which cannot activate until after rule 1.

This is what is known as "inference", and is an important tool for good rule design. Mark Proctor (Drools lead) wrote a good blog entry about it here:

http://blog.athico.com/2009/11/what-is-inference-and-how-does-it.html

Comment: Hello Steve, Thank you so much for the replay. That is the article I needed to read. My problem arises when I have to add a new rule, say "not Pregnant", where I have to do something when person is NOT HasBeenPregnant( person == $p ). This inference rule doesn't work sometimes (as expected). So, any suggestion on how to overcome this?

Comment: It should generally be fine. I suspect your unexpected behaviour probably comes because there are two reasons why HasBeenPregnant is not in working memory. First because the patient has never been pregnant, but also when rule 2 has not yet activated. One option would be to ensure that the rules above have higher "salience", to ensure that they are activated first. An alternative, probably safer  option could be to create a separate HasNeverBeenPregnant fact, and write rules against that rather than assuming that non-existence of HasBeenPregnant implies the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Steve. From the logs, I see that the behavior was because the rule hasn't been activated yet. I like the second proposal(because, don't want to introduce flow control using salience).But, sometimes the actual condition in the rules are huge connect with "and" condition. Negating all the conditions doubles my development effort. Also, as you are aware, we have to negate using "OR" condition and that runs the outcome of the rule more than once if more than one condition becomes true, which is undesirable. Any better way of doing this?minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: For one thing, the rules could check in the LHS for the facts they insert. That way, as soon as a rule activates to insert an inferred fact, then all other rules which would insert it don't need to be evaluated any more. Another thing to consider is that you don't have to do all conditional evaluation on the LHS. You could have a rule which matches on the bare Person(), and has an "if-then-else" on the RHS.